# Can Ember on and observer be chained and applied to one method using the new Ember.computed syntax?

Tags: ember.js

I have recently started switching from syntax like this:

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  someMethod: function(){
    // do something
  }.on('init')
});
```

to this:

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  someMethod: Ember.on('init', function() {
    // do something
  })
});
```

Because it seems to be the convention nowadays and I hear it works better in add-ons.

However, occasionally I want to chain behaviors of the method like this:

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  someMethod: function(){
    // do something
  }.on('init').observes('someProperty')
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this with the syntax that doesn't count on having function prototypes modified to include `on` and `observes` methods?

Comment: I'm far away of knowing the answer but am curious to learn. Have you tried to chain `observes` in the new syntax? like `Ember.on('init', function(){}).obrserves('property', function(){})`

Comment: I don't think it's possible after looking at the Ember source code...but I suppose you could add an observer inside `someMethod` using `addObserver`....but I don't think that's as readable as the chain you propose above.

Answer (score 0):

`function() {}.on('init')` does not work in addons because `Function` prototype extensions are disabled by default in addons. This was done so they work with applications that also have them turned off.

In this case, `Ember.on('init', function() {}).observes('someProperty')` is not considered a prototype extension because you are calling the `.observes()` function on whatever is returned from the `.on()` function.

You should avoid using `.on()` with lifecycle hooks, specifically `.on('init')`. The `.on()` event listener is asynchronous, leading to unexpected event execution ordering. The better alternative is to [override the init method](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances):

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Another suggested improvement is that starting with Ember 1.13 you have [new lifecycle hooks available](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/). This allows you to replace the `.on()` + `.observes()` with for example [`didReceiveAttrs`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_formatting-component-attributes-with-code-didreceiveattrs-code):

```
Ember.Object.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    // check if `someProperty` changed
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I just don't think it's possible with chaining, but if you need to do that with non-deprecated syntax this may work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Observe and Chain Demo',
  clicks: 0,
  someProp: 'undefined',

  bindOnInitAndPropChange: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.set('someProp', `Initialized. I see ${ this.get('clicks') } clicks.`); 
    Ember.addObserver(this, 'clicks', null, function() {
      this.set('someProp', `Observed, I now see ${ this.get('clicks') } clicks.`);
    });
  }),

  actions: {
    incrementClicks() {
      this.incrementProperty('clicks');  
    }
  }
});
```

[Working Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3da249e2ea3445553f148fe1694c7202?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)